# Adding Custom Libraries to CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, fpdf

I have these following class declaration in CodeIgniter:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

if (session_status()==PHP_SESSION_NONE){
    session_start();
}

require_once(APPPATH.'libraries/fpdf/fpdf17/fpdf.php');

class Fpdf {
    var $ci;
    var $pdf;
    public function __construct(){
        $this->ci =& get_instance();
        $this->pdf = new FPDF();
    }

    public function t(){
        echo 'Orayt!';
    }

    public function generateResume(){
        $this->pdf->AddPage();
        $u_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
        $this->db->where('user_id',$u_id);
        $data = $this->db->get('user');
        // Header
        foreach($data->result() as $row){
            $mName = $row->middle_name; $name = $row->first_name . ' ' . $mName[0] . '. ' . $row->last_name;
            $this->pdf->Cell(0,0,$name,0,1);
        }
        $this->pdf->Output();
    }

    public function testPDF(){
        $this->pdf->AddPage();
        $this->pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
        $this->pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
        $this->pdf->Output();
    }
}

?>
```

My problem is that when I load it into a controller using `$this->load->library('fpdf');` it doesn't load.

Could someone please help me in finding how to correct this error? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

user guide :
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html

Check Your file name, use the same name for class name and file name.

and i think it will help us if you capture or copy your error, why you say it doesn't load ?

```
 public function __construct(){
        $this->ci =& get_instance();
        $this->pdf = new FPDF();
    }
```

you use this code, $his->ci  Assigning by reference allows you to use the original CodeIgniter object rather than creating a copy of it.

so if you want call or use CI librari you must like this example,

$data = $this->db->get('user');
 cange to :
$data = **$this->ci**->db->get('user');

Comment: It doesn't output any errors. I just can't load the library

Comment: try to add your code when you call the library at your controller, or copy your method and paste here so we know what do you need .

Comment: This is the part of the code that I use to load the library: 
`public function __construct() {`
`parent::__construct();`
`$this->load->library('facebook');`
`$this->load->library('fpdf'); `

Comment: you just load the library and not using it ?

Comment: I am using it. I created a public function calling the function located in the library

Comment: example : $data = $this->db->get('user'); cange to : $data = $this->ci->db->get('user');

Comment: you create public function or private function it's same if you not call it, then the metod won't running.

Comment: It still doesn't load sir.

Comment: `public function tpdf(){
        $this->fpdf->testPDF();
    }`

Comment: the output is blank ?

Comment: Nope. There is no PDF outputed. Even though I already called `$pdf->Output();`

Answer (score 0):

maybe Use this if you not load CI_Controler ?

```
$ci = & get_instance();
$ci->load->library('name');
```

Comment: Or add your libraries in autoloader.php

Comment: It still doesn't load after following the suggested steps sir.